# Geth not syncing

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, fast-sync

Apparently my installation of Geth breaks after some day of working, and log is not clear to me:

```
WARN [03-16|12:50:49] Synchronisation failed, retrying         err="state node 266e74…51868f failed with all peers (2 tries, 2 peers)"
WARN [03-16|12:50:59] Node data write error                    err="state node 266e74…51868f failed with all peers (2 tries, 2 peers)"
WARN [03-16|12:50:59] Synchronisation failed, retrying         err="state node 266e74…51868f failed with all peers (2 tries, 2 peers)"
WARN [03-16|12:51:09] Node data write error                    err="state node 266e74…51868f failed with all peers (2 tries, 2 peers)"
WARN [03-16|12:51:09] Synchronisation failed, retrying         err="state node 266e74…51868f failed with all peers (2 tries, 2 peers)"
WARN [03-16|12:51:19] Node data write error                    err="state node 266e74…51868f failed with all peers (2 tries, 2 peers)"
WARN [03-16|12:51:19] Synchronisation failed, retrying         err="state node 266e74…51868f failed with all peers (2 tries, 2 peers)"
INFO [03-16|12:51:30] Imported new block headers               count=7    elapsed=36.176ms  number=5265382 hash=002ec2…b4af02 ignored=166
WARN [03-16|12:51:32] Node data write error                    err="state node 266e74…51868f failed with all peers (2 tries, 2 peers)"
WARN [03-16|12:51:32] Rolled back headers                      count=7    header=5265382->5265375 fast=5265209->5265209 block=0->0
WARN [03-16|12:51:32] Synchronisation failed, retrying         err="state node 266e74…51868f failed with all peers (2 tries, 2 peers)"
WARN [03-16|12:51:39] Node data write error                    err="state node 266e74…51868f failed with all peers (2 tries, 2 peers)"
WARN [03-16|12:51:39] Synchronisation failed, retrying         err="state node 266e74…51868f failed with all peers (2 tries, 2 peers)"
WARN [03-16|12:51:49] Node data write error                    err="state node 266e74…51868f failed with all peers (2 tries, 2 peers)"
WARN [03-16|12:51:49] Synchronisation failed, retrying
```

I have no idea how to solve this.
Furthermore, if I call

```
eth.syncing
```

it returns `false`

But I dont receive any newBlocks event from websocket subscription.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting geth must solve the problem, i also had same issue and after restarting it works like a charm

Comment: belive it or not, I tryed :)

Comment: may be your blockchain is upto date and there is nothing more to sync

Comment: so why no events?

Comment: if eth.syncing  returns false, it means blockchain is fully synced. Try eth.blockNumber to check last synced block and match it with any explorer

Comment: canneven mean nor syncing at all as far as I know. eth.blockNumber is zero when using --fast

Answer (score 1):

Update to go1.10 version and recreate your chain.

Comment: This will not work.

Answer (score 0):

maybe too basic... but check your port is open. 
i run into that kinda issue quite often but generally restarting the geth resolves the problem, or just waiting and giving it another go later also works.